# Replace all characters in p tags using javascript replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have data displaying on my website from an XML feed. Unfortunately in the XML feed the owner has used grave accents: ` instead of apostrophies: '

I am using the following javascript to try and replace the grave accents with apostrophes but it only works for the first grave accent in the content. How can I adjust the code to make it affect all grave accents inside the p tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("p").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("`", "'");
    $(this).text(text);
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression with the "global" (`g`) flag:

```
text = text.replace(/`/g, "'");
```

When you use a string for the first argument, only the first match is replaced (as you discovered). With the `g` flag, all matches are replaced. (Obviously be careful if you're using any characters that are special in regular expressions, being sure to escape them. For instance, if you wanted to replace all `[` characters, you'd need a `\` before the `[` to escape it as otherwise it has special meaning in a regex.)

See also [Ricardo's note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689371/157247) about using the ability to pass a function to [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) directly instead of using `each`, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("p").text(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/`/g, "'");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape a ` character?

Comment: @donderpiet: Nope, it's not special in regular expressions. `"testing ` ` `".replace(/`/g, "'")` results in `"testin ' ' '"`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `each`

```
$('p').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/\`/g, "'");
});
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer on `text`. Might also want to mention the regex thing (which you've used, but not mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular expression - something like:

```
text = text.replace(/`/gi, "'");
```

Regular replace only replaces the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a greedy regexp:

```
text = text.replace(/`/g, "'");
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your vocabulary is greedy! :)